# execution of the current web request. Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: asp.net

Please do not down vote. i am new to this site.
i tried myself but repeatedly the same error occurring.

```css
protected void gvDepPayment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDeptName");
            DataTable dT = (DataTable)ViewState["DataBounded"];
            DataRow[] drows = dT.Select("DepartmentName = '" + lbl.Text + "'");
            int Count = 0;
            foreach (DataRow item in drows)
            {
                Count += Convert.ToInt32(item["PaidAmount"]);
            }
            Label lblPaidAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPaidAmount");
            lblPaidAmount.Text = Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvDepPayment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                    OnRowDataBound="gvDepPayment_RowDataBound">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department Name">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblDeptName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DepartmentName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Collection">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPaidAmount" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

i want find the Payment list and show it in grid view like Department wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is caused by your reading the content of the DataRow at the column named `PaidAmount`, probably there are some null values in the set of rows returned by your query. In this scenario you could use the [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the DataRow class with the conditional operator. In the case of DBNull.Value you want to add zero to your count.

```
Count += item.IsNull("PaidAmount") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item["PaidAmount"]);
```